# Как создать таблицу неповторяющихся элементов из двух других таблиц?

Tags: mysql

Добрый день!

Я уже как-то спрашивал, как из двух одинаковых по структуре таблиц БД выбрать неповторяющиеся элементы (результаты прошлого парсинга сайта и нового, хочу получить список того, что добавили новенького на сайт). Так вот, мне посоветовали воспользоваться вот такой конструкцией:

```
SELECT p.* 
FROM `{таблица новый товаров}` as p
WHERE p.product_id NOT IN (
   SELECT product_id
   FROM `{таблица старых товаров}`
)
```

`product_id`  - содержит уникальные значения (артикулы товаров донора, они 100% уникальны). Запрос прекрасно работает, сравниваются две таблицы по 35-40 тысяч товаров, возвращается результат ~8000 новых товаров.

Проблема в том, что запрос выполняется долго, и использовать его в парсере (чтобы слить только новинки) нельзя. Я знаю, что как-то можно создавать таблицы и записывать в них результат другой выборки. Но все мои опыты не увенчались успехом.

Может, кто-то сталкивался с подобной проблемой? Как мне подкорректировать текущий запрос, чтобы полученные ~8000 товаров засунуть в 3-ю (отдельную) таблицу и спокойно парсить дальше?

Comment: Если за раз выполняется только одна копия скрипта, то можно заранее создать таблицу и при каждом запуске очищать ее и вставлять туда ваши 8К записей.

И не пробовали как-то улучшить время работы? Профилирование проводили? Индексы есть?

Может, в такой форме лучше будет:

    SELECT p.* 
    FROM `{таблица новый товаров}` as p

    LEFT JOIN `{таблица старых товаров}` AS o
    USING(product_id)

    WHERE o.product_id IS NULL

А если есть еще данные (типа даты), то можно и их задействовать, чтобы сразу отсечь лишнее.

Comment: Я думал это попробовать только MySQL сделать, но можно впринципе и через php скрипт, просто полуить эти записи текущим скриптом и записать их в заранее подготовленную таблицу. Хотя MySQL было бы предпочтительнее.

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете воспользоваться оператором `INSERT ... SELECT ...`, который позволяет использовать результаты SELECT-запроса в качестве источника для INSERT-вставки

```
INSERT INTO
  `{промежуточная таблица}`
SELECT p.* 
FROM `{таблица новый товаров}` as p
WHERE p.product_id NOT IN (
   SELECT product_id
   FROM `{таблица старых товаров}`
)
```